# How to automate the closure of PRs without linked issue using GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have my project open source and I noticed that we have a lot of pull requests that don't mention the issue that they address. I think having this GitHub Actions workflow would be helpful with this problem.

I don't have much experience with GitHub Actions and PR without issues mentioned are just looking like spammed PRs so I want to get rid of them.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a GHA workflow with [`on.schedule`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onschedule) that would run once per day (or manually using [`on.workflow_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_dispatch) or however you want it to run).

In this workflow, you may use [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) to automate this.

Use [`gh pr list`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_list) to get the list of numbers of all the open PRs:

```bash
gh pr list --repo owner/repo --json number --jq '.[] | join("")'
```

Loop through this list, and use `gh api`  to query using GraphQL as it's [not yet implemented](https://github.com/cli/cli/discussions/7097#discussioncomment-5229031) directly in the GitHub CLI as a separate command:

```bash
gh api graphql -F owner='{owner}' -F repo='{repo}' -F pr=PRNUMBER -f query='
query ($owner: String!, $repo: String!, $pr: Int!) {
    repository(owner: $owner, name: $repo) {
        pullRequest(number: $pr) {
            closingIssuesReferences(first: 100) {
                nodes {
                    number
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'  --jq '.data.repository.pullRequest.closingIssuesReferences.nodes[].number'
```

The above query will return the number of the linked issue, nothing otherwise. You may use this for your decision making and run [`gh pr close`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_close) accordingly.

---

Here's a complete example as a Bash script:

[`gh-close-prs.bash`](https://gist.github.com/iamazeem/6411ffddcdb4f2d4717c9ddfb463d57c)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e

owner=""        # owner name here
repo=""         # repo name here

prs=$(gh pr list --repo "$owner/$repo" --json number --jq '.[] | join("")')

for pr in $prs; do
    issue=$(gh api graphql -F owner="$owner" -F repo="$repo" -F pr="$pr" -f query='
        query ($owner: String!, $repo: String!, $pr: Int!) {
            repository(owner: $owner, name: $repo) {
                pullRequest(number: $pr) {
                    closingIssuesReferences(first: 100) {
                        nodes {
                            number
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }'  --jq '.data.repository.pullRequest.closingIssuesReferences.nodes[].number')

    if [[ -z $issue ]]; then
        echo "PR [$pr] linked issue not found, closing"
        gh pr close --repo "$owner/$repo" "$pr"
    else
        echo "PR [$pr] linked issue found: $issue"
    fi
done
```

Do not forget to make it executable before pushing to your repo:

```bash
chmod +x gh-close-prs.bash
```

---

Your workflow would be (assuming that the above script is located in the `scripts` directory):

`.github/workflows/gh-close-prs.yml`

```yaml
name: Close PRs without linked issues

on:
  workflow_dispatch:        # for manual run
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 1 * * *'     # https://crontab.guru/every-day-at-1am

jobs:
  cron:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Run script
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: ./scripts/gh-close-prs.bash
```

See [Using GitHub CLI in workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/using-github-cli-in-workflows) for more details.

You may further refine it according to your use case.